# How to change a link image on mouse over on jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to change a link image on mouse hover. I used the following code but does not work. Perhaps the problem is with the image source but I still cannot find what's wrong with he code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head><title>Edit Document</title> 

<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lnkEdit").hover(
        function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace("../images/edit_off.gif", "../images/edit_on.png");
        },
        function () {
            this.src = this.src.replace("../images/edit_on.png", "../images/edit_off.gif");
        }
        );
    });

</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form method="post" action="Hover4.aspx" id="form1"> 
<div class="aspNetHidden"> 
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNTkwNjIyODQxZGR6kotcsbIsWRfokZrzasCtfPi0dxz4MBWWh9VxSJ6R0Q==" /> 
</div> 

<div> 
    <a id="HyperLink1" href="Hover4.aspx"><img src="../images/edit_off.gif" alt="HyperLink" /></a> 
</div> 
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are referencing `#lnkEdit` in your code but there is no element with that ID on the page
2. You don't need `replace` or any special functions, you can simply assign the new image source.

Try something like this:

**JavaScript** (updated as per comments)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#your_table_id > a').hover(
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_on.png');
    },
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_off.png');
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I overlooked item 1.
I used your code but still does not work change on hover.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the `#` for `MyImage`. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works if I use an image button but still does not work with the hyperlink. The hyperlink runs on the server side 
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Edit_Off.gif">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
and does not let me use the id="MyImage" because it already uses id="Hyperlink1"
Any other suggestion?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated the code so that it doesn't need the image ID - it directly references the `<img>` tag inside the link now.

Comment: Your code works. I failed to mention, however, that I wanted to have the the link on a datalist. When I use your code, it replaces the first link on the table but the other remaining links do not change when I hover over them. Sorry for not mentioning that I wanted to have a list with the links rather than just one link.

Comment: Updated. Just replace your table's ID in the code and it will work for all links in the table.

Comment: Still does not change the image. I pasted your code with the table Id:

        $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlOpenRequests > a').hover(
        function() {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/Edit_On.png');
        },
        function() {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/Edit_Off.png');
        });

Comment: I tried it myself and it works. We will have to look at your table structure to find out what might be going wrong.

Comment: I will post the code but might have to modify the original posted script. Is that OK with you?

Answer (score 0):

credits must go to @casablanca, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each($('#your_table_id > a'), functio(i, item) {
    $(item).hover(
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_on.png');
    },
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_off.png');
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: You don't even need to wrap it in `each()`: most jQuery functions apply to all matched elements anyway.

Comment: I used the code and it does not change a single image. Below is the change:

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.each($('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlOpenRequests > a'), function(i, item) {
        $(item).hover(
        function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_on.gif');
        },
        function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '../images/edit_off.gif');
        });
        });

Thanks for the help.